# Drawing Polygons

Tags: html, css

When you specify a polygon area for an image map, you just list the co-ordinates of the points. Using a similar method, is it possible to draw a polygon using html and css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw polygons using SVG. Here's an [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=polygon1&type=svg).

Answer (score 1):

You can draw polygons with the HTML5 canvas.  Here's just one of many examples out there on the Web:

http://www.kozlenko.info/blog/2010/11/19/how-to-calulate-polygon-points-for-html5-canvas/

Although [polygons with pure HTML and CSS](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/image_free_css_tooltip_pointers_a_use_for_polygonal_css/) are technically possible, it seems like a nasty hack to me.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions so far only work on IE9 or higher. If you need to draw vector graphics on older versions of IE, then take a look at [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), which abstracts SVG and VML (Microsofts proprietary vector format) with a common JS-API.